# Get the count of code complexity due to type of control structures line by line into a table view

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I have developed a desktop application using java swing using the netbeans IDE. The purpose of it is to measure the complexity of a program statement due to the type of control structures. For a program statement with "if", "for", "while" and "catch", a weight of 1, 2, 2, and 1 are assigned respectively. Additionally, a weight of "n" is assigned for a program statement with a "switch" statement with "n" number of cases. All other statements are assigned with a weight of zero.

I have implemented the solution for the above problem already, and I need to demonstrate the complexity "of each program statement" in a tabular format. I have used a jTable for that purpose with the column names "Line no", "Program statement" and "Complexity count".

Though I have taken the total count of complexity, I have no idea about getting the count line by line and display it in the jTable. The complexity count relevant for each program statement should be displayed against each line number and the statement.

Here is my code. 
https://github.com/nirmaniPathiranage/Complexity-measuring-tool/blob/master/src/spm/FilesDemo.java

I have implemented the function of loading table data from the line 733 onwards. (action performed on jButton11).

```
private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton11ActionPerformed{}
```

I expect the output of complexity for each program statement against each line number and program statement in a table view.

I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this about McCabe / cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: You're iterating the lines of code, right? And determining the complexity of that line, so you can add it to the total, right? So I don't see what the problem is with recording a list of linenumber/complexity pairs, so you can show it in a table. What exactly is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I have already got the total code complexity, but I do not understand how to load it into a table view, as to display the complexity line by line. Please can any support be provided?

Comment: I guess, the calculation is already done accurately. It is just a need of loading the count into a table, against each program statement.(count for each line separately)

Comment: *"Here is my code. [link]"* Nope. All relevant code (a [mre]) should be included right here in the question. Please [edit] to add an MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible issue i can see with implementing a jTable to show complexities for each line in a program is not knowing the number of lines before hand. But this too can be solved easily with a naive approach of using an *ArrayList<>*  and a *TableModel* as in below.

```
//Names of the columns
String columns[] = {"Line no","Program statement","Complexity count"};

//Table model, initiate with 0 columns
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

To make things clearer, implementing a POJO class for contents to be showed in a table row would be ideal.

```
public class TableRow {
   private int lineNo;
   private String statement;
   private int cmplxCount;

   //You may implement the getters and setters as well
}
```

While the program iterates through each and every line calculating the complexity, make sure to create a new *TableRow* object and necessary data and add them to an *ArrayList*

```
ArrayList<TableRow> list = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
//Create an object each time a line is iterated for complexity calculations.
TableRow newRow = new TableRow(4,"for-loop",1);
list.add(newRow);
```

After the iteration is over, add those data in the ArrayList to an Object array and pass them to the jTable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   int lineNo= list.get(i).getLineNo();
   String statment = list.get(i).getStatement();
   int cmplxCount= list.get(i).getCmplxCount();

   Object[] data = {lineNo, statement , cmplxCount};
   tableModel.add(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now only I got the idea of how to deal with this issue. Thanks again